# Mod_Rewriting based on a GET variable

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

So -- I've used mod rewrite a few thousand times to do things like changing **url.tld/show/season/1** to load **video.php?show=someshow&season=1.**

However -- Now i need to do the opposite, show a temporary HTML page instead of serving PHP on those pages.

myshows.com/seasons/?sid=1

I've tried doing a rewrite cond including the ?, but it never seems to work.

RewriteRule ^/seasons/\?sid=1 migrating.html

**EDIT** I need to make sure the only page effected is the SID=1, not any of the other possible season ID's

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a bit of work to find, but

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sid=1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /migrating.html
```

Did the trick.

Comment: This will work until someone asks for season 10 (sid=10).  If sid= is always at the end, add a $ after it to mark it as the end of line.  Otherwise, you might have to do this twice, once with `sid=1$` and once `sid=1&`.  I *think* `sid=1($|&)` should work.

Comment: Yea, Already discovered that. :p  Found the error :)